# ETW provider is not discovered automatically for the Service Fabric Stateless ASP.NET Core project type

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have created a "Service Fabric Application" using the "Stateless ASP.NET Core" template found in Visual Studio 2017 Pro 15.3.5. I am using using Service Fabric SDK 2.7.198.

And every time I hit F5 to deploy the sample app to my local SF cluster, the Diagnostic Events window notifies me that there are no ETW providers found in the solution. Could this be because it's a .NET core project using the new .csproj format?

Because when I create a "Service Fabric Application" using the "Stateless Service" template, the ETW providers list is automatically updated to include the provider from the sample Stateless1 app. And the stateless's app project is using the old .csproj format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have double-checked and I have used SF tools 1.8. It was installed during my upgrade to VS 15.4. So I decided to do a clean install of VS 15.4.

I have removed my VS 15.4 installation and manually uninstalled SF SDK 2.8.211 and SF runtime 6.0.211. I have then installed VS 15.4 from scratch. And then installed SF runtime 6.0.219 and SF SDK 2.8.219 (these were the latest at the time of installation) via the Web Platform Installer. I have double-checked that I have version 1.8.20170927.3 of the SF tools installed in Visual Studio.

I reopened my existing sample projects (both Stateless ASP.NET core and Stateless) and the ETW sources were harvested automatically. I have also created a new sample Stateless ASP.NET core project and the ETW sources were also harvested automatically.

So everything works now. Thank you for your support.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a known issue that has been fixed in 2.8 release of Fabric SDK, which is due to be published in the Microsoft Ignite 2017 timeframe (end of September).

As a workaround you can just add the relevant provider name explicitly via Diagnostic Events window configuration.

Sorry!

Comment: Is it written in the 2.8 release plan of the Service Fabric SDK? Or is there a link to a preview of the 2.8 SDK? I would like to check it to make sure. Then I'll wait for the release of the 2.8 SDK. I have applied the workaround you've mentioned and got it working. But I thought it should be working out of the box, that's why I ask/reported the issue. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: You should be able to download SDK 2.8 now via Web Platform Installer. Please give it a try and let us know if the problem is fixed--thx!

Comment: I have updated the SF runtime to 6.0.211 and the SF SDK to 2.8.211 using the latest Web Platform Installer. The issue is still present. 
Is there also a new version of the SF tools for Visual Studio 2017 Pro 15.3.5? Because the newly created SF ASP.NET core project still references SF 5.7.198 and 2.7.198 assemblies.

Comment: OK, sorry for misleading you--turns out the updated Visual Studio tooling has not been released yet. It should be available next week (via Visual Studio update).

Comment: I have upgraded to Visual Studio 15.4 and created both a "Stateless" and a "Stateless ASP.NET Core" sample project. For both projects, no ETW sources were discovered automatically when starting to debug the app (F5). And the Diagnostic Events window is Disconnected.
Is that the expected behavior? Do I need to manually add ETW sources from now on?

Comment: And my existing solution with multiple SF apps is now no longer showing any ETW sources in the Diagnostic Events window.

Comment: My existing SF applications that used to work are no longer showing any events and nothing in the drop down for ETW providers. Tried "View Streaming Traces" in Cloud Explorer. Tried reinstalling all. VS 2017 15.5.2, SF SDK 2.8.232.